# HTML input type=submit won't fire in rails app when very similar button works?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

Environment is Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1, Simple Form, IE or Firefox.

I am having trouble getting HTML input type=submit to fire in the edit action.  The new action is very nearly the same and it works consistently.  In this case, I have eliminated almost all inputs and submenus on the form to simplify this particular issue.

When I click on the submit button in the new action, it fires the controller create action.  When I click on the submit button in the edit action, literally nothing happens.  No trace information occurs in the log or in the client console of any action whatsoever.  The controller update action is not fired.  In both cases, breakpoints show that @car is referencing the appropriate car object.

I am using standard HTML for the submit because the form button never works with the complex menus I am building.  I use the form attribute to associate the button with the form and have triple-checked to ensure that the form specified in the HTML input tag matches that in the form, either new_car or edit_car.

The controller actions are:

```
  def edit
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end
```

Routing is defined using:

```
  resources :cars
```

new.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'new', layout: 'layouts/sf_label', locals: { title: 'New Car' } %>
</div>
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'edit', layout: 'layouts/sf_label', locals: { title: 'Edit Car' } %>
</div>
```

The working "new" partial form is:

```
<div class="span8">
  <%= simple_form_for @car,
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input(:stock_number, {input_html: {form: 'new_car', car: @car},  autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Stock number?'}) %>
      <input type="submit" form="new_car" value="Create Car" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary">
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The failing "edit" partial is:

```
<div class="span8">
  <%= simple_form_for @car,
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input(:stock_number, {input_html: {form: 'edit_car', car: @car}, autocomplete: :off, placeholder: 'Stock number?'}) %>
      <input type="submit" form="edit_car" value="Update Car" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary">
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The HTML form and button for new_car is:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Stock number?" name="car[stock_number]" id="car_stock_number" form="new_car" class="string required" car="#&lt;Car:0x9830ef8&gt;">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary" value="Create Car" form="new_car">
```

The HTML form and button for edit_car is:

```
<input type="text" value="AStock" placeholder="Stock number?" name="car[stock_number]" id="car_stock_number" form="edit_car" class="string required" car="#&lt;Car:0x62ebd08&gt;">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary" value="Update Car" form="edit_car">
```

Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pg'
gem 'simple_form', '3.0.1'
gem 'thin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'acts_as_tenant'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'  # For Heroku
  end
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require=>false
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Generated form tag for new_car:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" method="post" id="new_car" class="simple_form form-vertical" action="/cars" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Generated form tag for edit_car:

```
<form id="edit_car_53" class="simple_form form-vertical" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="/cars/53" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Could it be the `form="edit_car"` that makes it not work? Have you tried using `form="new_car"` as for the new action?

Comment: Well, the form attribute for the button should be the same as the form attribute in the form, which is edit_car.  However, under the concept of trying anything once, I tried it.  Same result, basically no response.  But, thanks.

Comment: How you submit the form? Do you use Javascript to scan the form then submitting it if valid?

Comment: I have jQuery running in the form when the full form is in use.  In attempt to diagnose this issue, I have eliminated all of those inputs and deleted the jQuery code, as well.  This problem has no JavaScript code that I have provided, however SimpleForm and other gems may have js code.

Comment: I added the Gemfile FYI.

Comment: Could you share the generated html `<form>` tag in both cases please.

Comment: Have you tried using a button type=submit instead of an input type=submit.
Is there a request being sent when you click on the button? If not can you hover over the button and show us the path it's trying to go to. If there is a request can you inspect it and show whether it's post or get and if there's an error.

Comment: @Graeme McLean -- Okay, added the generated form tags and that seems to be a hit.  I see the form is different than I expected, which would cause the problem, including the 304 not modified.  I'll have to make some changes to include the car id within the form values throughout the form, I guess.

Comment: @TheJKFever -- I think Graeme McLean has the right direction.  See above.  Thanks.

Comment: @Graeme McLean -- Actually, I just added id: 'edit_car' into the form definition and it fires!  Please update your response to a formal answer so that I can accept.  Thanks to all that helped!

Comment: The form= in your submit button, and the id of the form need to be the same. Glad you found the answer

Comment: I think you solved it yourself - I just pointed you to look at something you maybe didn't already consider.  You should post your own answer to help out anyone else who hits something similar in the future.  You should be able to accept it but I think you have to wait some time before you can do this on your own answer.  Glad it's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by Graeme McLean, I entered the HTML form tags into the question.  There, I noted that the form attribute was not edit_car, as I expected but instead was edit_car_[:id], for example edit_car_53.  As a result, the submit button was disconnected from the form and would not fire.  To resolve this problem, I updated the form to just use edit_car, as follows:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @car,
                      defaults: {label: false},
                      html: {id: 'edit_car', class: 'form-vertical'},
                      wrapper: :vertical_form,
                      wrapper_mappings: {
                              check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                              file: :vertical_file_input,
                              boolean: :vertical_boolean
                      } do |f| %>
```

This resolved that particular problem, thanks to the many that responded and especially Graeme.